# appium doctor, warning about Xcode is shown though it is included in the path

Tags: appium

I get this warning from appium-doctor.

WARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ Manually install Xcode, and make sure 'xcode-select -p' command shows proper path like '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'

But the command 'xcode-select -p' returns a valid path. 
% xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
%

Can I ignore this warning, or should I fix anything?